# Straight-line drawing of regular polyhedra

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, computational-complexity, plane-geometry, extremal-combinatorics

> Find the minimum number of straight lines needed to cover a crossing-free straight-line drawing of the icosahedron $(13\dots 15)$ and of the dodecahedron $(9\dots 10)$ (in the plane).

For example, the cube can be covered by 7 lines:

[image]

(The problem was posed 13.10.2017 by Alexander Wolff and Alexander Ravsky on page [78](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/viewpage.php?page=78) of [Volume 1](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka/viewbook.php?vol=1) of the [Lviv Scottish Book](http://www.math.lviv.ua/szkocka).

The prize for solution: *A bottle of Franconia wine!*).

Comment: That's the funniest-looking cube I've ever seen. It's a cube only a combinatorialist could love.

Comment: There are different kinds of Franconian wine; I hope the one offered is worth the effort (I lived in Wuerzburg for 30 years).

Comment: I'm a bit confused by what's meant when you write $(13 \dots 15)$ and $(9 \dots 10)$. Are these known bounds on the numbers of lines needed for each graph? (If so I'm impressed by your upper bounds -- my first attempts came nowhere close!) Or is it something else?

Comment: @WillBrian Thanks for your interest to our problem. Yes, your are right, in the brackets are the known bounds.  
See our paper “[Drawing Graphs on Few Circles and Few Spheres](https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.06965)”, namely p. 6 for the upper bounds and Proposition 6 for the lower bounds.